# echo -e acts differently when run in a script by root on ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, echo

When running a bash script on ubuntu 9.10, I get different behavior from bash echo's "-e" option depending on whether or not I'm running as root.

Consider this script:

```
$ cat echo-test
if [ "`whoami`" = "root" ]; then
  echo "Running as root" 
fi
echo Testing /bin/echo -e
/bin/echo -e "foo\nbar"
echo Testing bash echo -e
echo -e "foo\nbar"
```

When run as non-root user, I see this output:

```
$ ./echo-test 
Testing /bin/echo -e
foo
bar
Testing bash echo -e
foo
bar
```

When run as root, I see this output:

```
$ sudo ./echo-test 
Running as root
Testing /bin/echo -e
foo
bar
Testing bash echo -e
-e foo
bar
```

Notice the "-e" being echoed in the last case ("-e foo" instead of "foo" on the second-to-last line).  When running a script as root, the echo command runs as if "-e" was given and, if -e is given, the option itself is echoed.

I can understand some subtle differences in behavior between /bin/echo and bash echo, but I would expect bash echo to behave the same no matter which user invokes it.

Anyone know why this is the case?  Is this a bug in bash echo?

*FYI -- I'm running GNU bash, version 4.0.33(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you sure that your user and root both use bash as their shell?
try putting a "shebang" line (#!/bin/bash) in your script as first line, and run it again

Comment: #!/bin/bash at the top fixes it.  So root must be using a different shell with a different echo.  That makes sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting to see the value of POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable and to determine whether xpg_echo shell option is enabled in both situations.

```
if test -n "${POSIXLY_CORRECT+yes}"; then
    pc="set '$POSIXLY_CORRECT'"
else
    pc=unset
fi
echo POSIXLY_CORRECT: "$pc"
shopt -q xpg_echo && xe=set || xe=unset
echo xpg_echo: $xe
```

Here is the test code I used to examine the various combinations:

```
{ n=1
for p in '' p; do
    for x in '' x; do
        for e in '' e; do
            printf "\nmode: ${p:-_}${x:-_}${e:-_}\n"
            test -n "$x" && xx=-s || xx=-u
            bash ${p:+--posix} -c "              shopt $xx xpg_echo
              test -n \"\${POSIXLY_CORRECT+yes}\" && pc=\"set '\$POSIXLY_CORRECT'\" || pc=unset
              shopt -q xpg_echo && xe=set || xe=unset
              echo POSIXLY_CORRECT: \"\$pc\"
              echo xpg_echo: \$xe
              echo${e:+ -e} \"$n\n$((n+1))\"
            "
            n=$((n+2))
        done
    done
done
}
```

On my system, your “as root” effect is reproduce in the last case (both POSIXLY_CORRECT and xpg_echo are set).

```
mode: ___
POSIXLY_CORRECT: unset
xpg_echo: unset
1\n2

mode: __e
POSIXLY_CORRECT: unset
xpg_echo: unset
3
4

mode: _x_
POSIXLY_CORRECT: unset
xpg_echo: set
5
6

mode: _xe
POSIXLY_CORRECT: unset
xpg_echo: set
7
8

mode: p__
POSIXLY_CORRECT: set 'y'
xpg_echo: unset
9\n10

mode: p_e
POSIXLY_CORRECT: set 'y'
xpg_echo: unset
11
12

mode: px_
POSIXLY_CORRECT: set 'y'
xpg_echo: set
13
14

mode: pxe
POSIXLY_CORRECT: set 'y'
xpg_echo: set
-e 15
16
```

These variations in the behavior are the primary reason the use of *printf* is advocated over *echo*.

- An ‘informative’ (i.e. not [normative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative#Standards_documents)) part of the POSIX specification for the *echo* command [describes why *echo* can not be used portably](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html#tag_04_41_16) unless both escapes and trailing newline suppression features are not used.

  > New applications are encouraged to use *printf* instead of *echo*.
- See the *echo* entry under the [Limitations of Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html) section of the GNU Autoconf manual.
- While searching, I found [a random (but reasonable seeming) post](http://www.unix.com/302113949-post4.html) that describes *printf* as a standardization of *print* from *ksh*.
  It also says that *print* in *ksh* was created to avoid portability problems with *echo*.
- Apple's Shell Scripting Primer [recommends *printf* over *echo* when suppressing the trailing newline](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/opensource/conceptual/shellscripting/ShellInputandOutput/ShellInputandOutput.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-CH3-SW3).

Depending on the system and shell, sometimes *printf* is a shell built-in command and sometimes it is an external command, but its behavior is generally much more consistent than that of *echo*.

You can be sure that each of the following commands will produce an embedded newline and no trailing newline:

```
printf 'foo\nbar'
printf '%s\n%s' foo bar
```

BTW, this shows my preferred style of using single quotes for the format string to indicate that nothing funky is going into it (e.g. a parameter expansion that inserts an extra format specifier that is not reflected in the argument list).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 9.10 onward uses dash as default shell, instead of bash.

Dash can be consider a lightweight alternative of bash, but it has some minor incompatibility.  You should specify bash explicitly by "Shebang" sign

Comment: dash does not try to be compatible with bash -- dash tries to be compatible with POSIX sh, _and it does a better job than bash does_; bash _also_ tries to be compatible with POSIX sh, but `echo` is one of the places where bash's compatibility is wrong (except when running in an off-by-default stricter compatibility mode).