# bash built-in command compgen is not found when executing a script as sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, compgen

I have a set of tarballs in a directory. I want to select the "greatest" name of the tarballs (i.e. the first name when sorting in reverse order) and capture the name in a bash script variable. My example files are:

```
goyard@GoYard-BOXER-6404:~/Code/NodejsServer$ ls
reports-1.0.0.tgz  reports-1.1.0.tgz  reports-2.tgz
```

In this case, "reports-2.tgz" is the file I want.

From the bash command line, this works fine:

```
goyard@GoYard-BOXER-6404:~/Code/NodejsServer$ tarball_path=`compgen -G "report*.tgz" | sort -r | head -n 1`
goyard@GoYard-BOXER-6404:~/Code/NodejsServer$ echo $tarball_path
reports-2.tgz
```

In a bash shellscript, this same command succeeds:

The script:

```
# !/bin/bash

tarball_path=`compgen -G "report*.tgz" | sort -r | head -n 1`
echo "tarball_path: ${tarball_path}"
```

The script output:

```
goyard@GoYard-BOXER-6404:~/Code/NodejsServer$ ./get_report_name.sh
tarball_path: reports-2.tgz
```

But when I execute the script with sudo, the compgen built-in command cannot be found:

```
goyard@GoYard-BOXER-6404:~/Code/NodejsServer$ sudo ./get_report_name.sh
[sudo] password for goyard:
./get_report_name.sh: 1: compgen: not found
tarball_path:
```

I need to use sudo because I will eventually extract this tarball into the /srv directory on my Ubuntu box.

Note: This does not appear to be an issue of using the bash -e option because the compgen command is built in to bash - not *passed* in.

Why does sudo make a difference here?

... and how can I correct this?

Comment: compgen is an interactive extension. It's not guaranteed to be available in noninteractive shells at all, and on _some_ Linux distros (NixOS f/e) the default bash used for script execution (vs human-operated interactive shells) is compiled with interactive extensions turned off. Mind, you're surely not on NixOS, since `#!/bin/bash` wouldn't work as a shebang there.

Comment: That said, I'm pretty unclear on why you'd need compgen here. `lastMatch() { local val="${@:$#}"; if [[ -e $val || -L $val ]]; then printf '%s\n' "$val"; else return 1; fi; }` and you're done -- you can call `tarball_path=$(lastMatch report*.tgz)`. Or do something that uses indirect assignment to save to a named variable to eliminate the command substitution and get a corresponding efficiency increase. And if you get a syntax error from the bash-only syntax only when you use that through sudo, that would give us more hints about your problem.

Comment: One other thing -- `# !/bin/bash` is not a valid shebang; take out the space so it's just `#!/bin/bash`. That might actually fix the problem, if your script is being executed with `sh` as a fallback (which would explain `compgen` being unavailable). When you're starting from bash and an execve fails, it tries using itself as an interpreter, which would explain things looking like they work interactively even if they don't work in the more general case.

Comment: See [`echo -e` acts differently when run in a script by root on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931867/echo-e-acts-differently-when-run-in-a-script-by-root-on-ubuntu) for a different problem with the same root cause (which is to say, by scripts without a valid shebang being run by `sh` instead of `bash` when started via `sudo` on Ubuntu).

Comment: (personally, I'm on team "neither sudo nor bash should implement this 'helpful' fallback behavior; they should instead just fail explicitly when execve() doesn't work"; but alas, I don't rule the world)

Comment: Thank you Charles.  It *was* the space after the shebang that made the difference. Upon removing the space, the shellscript works as expected with sudo.

If you can make your third comment as an answer, I'll mark it as such.